# Get values from multiple columns and assign them button properties

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a room database and 6 buttons on windows form. I want to change button properties based on values from the database.

For example, buttons text should be `RoomNumber`, and button background color should be `RoomStatus`: if `RoomStatus = 0`, button background should be blue, 1 = yellow, 2 = red.

I only achieved to set the button's text, but I can't do background color:

```
void getRoomValue()
{
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmdGR = new SqlCommand("select RoomNum, RoomStatus  from RoomNumber", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmdGR.ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string buttonName = "button" + (1 + i).ToString();
            Control[] buttons = this.Controls.Find(buttonName, false);

            if (buttons.Length == 1 && buttons[0] is Button)
            {
                Button btn = (Button)buttons[0];
                btn.Text = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>("RoomNum");
            }       
        }
    }
```

[image: My Room Database]

Comment: You do not have buttons.  You have the header rows of you table that contains the names.

Comment: I have buttons on the windows form, I did not mention them here

Comment: Try following : string status = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>("RoomStatus");
switch(status)
{
   case "0" :
       btn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
       break;
   case "1" :
       btn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
       break;
   case "2" :
       btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
       break;
}

Comment: Yes, It is working as I want. Thank you very much